# Need to remove a vertical line in my header. Not sure how it's there

Tags: html, css

I have just made some links for the header on my site, however, after the second link there is a vertical grey line (the same as the divider between the header and the navbar)

I have tried to reorder the links and I have tried using different columns on bootstrap however only col-6 correctly aligns my links whereas any others such as col and col-4 don't give me this vertical line issue.

```css
.header-area {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
  -o-transition-duration: 500ms;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  background-color: #1c66de;
}

.header-area .top-header-area {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .header-area .top-header-area {
    z-index: 1;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .header-area .top-header-area {
    z-index: 1;
  }
}

.header-area .top-header-area .top-header-content {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-area .top-header-area .top-header-content a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Header Area Start -->
<header class="header-area">
  <!-- Top Header Area Start -->
  <div class="top-header-area">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="top-header-content">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-signal" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span>Status</span></a>
            <a href="~"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span>Support</span></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-money" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span>Billing</span></a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="top-header-content">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span>Login / Register</span></a>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Top Header Area End -->
```

I expect no line to be after the "support" link
http://prntscr.com/p8fzk9

Comment: I do not see a line!

Comment: @MadeInDreams check the screenshot and look closely. I can assure you there is a line

Comment: is that why your offsetting by 1 pixel?

Comment: href="~" ?? what is that for?

Comment: Let me know if it was that

Comment: @MadeInDreams it wasn't the '~', that was put there by mistake and wouldn't effect it regardless

Comment: where are the other class your using like fa but it's not in the css

Comment: The problem is not reproduced here. The line does not show up so it's impossible to help. I also copied everything to local dev and the problem does not show up. The result does not even match the image. Add what's needed or reproduce it in a fiddle or similar. Also specify the version of bootstrap (which could be affecting the result for me.)

Answer (score 0):

Added a class x for text decoration and the link underline was gone - if that's what you mean.

```
                <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>

                <head>
                    <title>Untitled</title>
                    <style>
                        body {
                            background-color:white;
                        }

                        .header-area .top-header-area {
                            position: relative;
                            z-index: 10;
                            width: 100%;
                            height: 50px;

                            border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
                        }


                        .x{
                                text-decoration: none !important;
                        }

                        @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
                            .header-area .top-header-area {
                                z-index: 1;
                            }


                            @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
                                .header-area .top-header-area {
                                    z-index: 1;

                                }



                                .header-area .top-header-area .top-header-content {
                                    display: -webkit-box;
                                    display: -ms-flexbox;
                                    display: flex;
                                    -webkit-box-align: center;
                                    -ms-flex-align: center;
                                    align-items: center;
                                }

                                .header-area .top-header-area .top-header-content a {
                                    color: #ffffff;
                                    font-size: 14px;
                                    font-weight: 400;
                                    line-height: 50px;
                                    display: inline-block;
                                }
                    </style>
                </head>

                <body>
                    <!-- Header Area Start -->
                    <header class="header-area">
                        <!-- Top Header Area Start -->
                        <div class="top-header-area">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <div class="top-header-content">
                                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-signal" aria-hidden="true">
                                            </i> <span>Status</span></a>
                                             <a href="~"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                             <span>Support</span></a>
                                             <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-money x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                             <span >Billing</span></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <div class="top-header-content">
                                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span>Login / Register</span></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Top Header Area End -->
                    </header>
                </body>

            </html>
```